# Composite Design Pattern: Should I insert add() and remove() in the Parent interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

Should I use add and remove method in the parent interface?

```
public interface Employee {

   public void add(Employee employee);
   public void remove(Employee employee);
   public void print();

}

Developer implements Employee{
.  @Override
   public void add(Employee employee) {
   //this is leaf node so this method is not applicable to this class.
   }

   @Override
   public void remove(Employee) {
   //this is leaf node so this method is not applicable to this class.
   }
   ..... 
   ......
}

Manager implements Employee{
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void add(Employee employee) {
       employees.add(employee);
    }    

    @Override
    public void remove(Employee employee) {
      employees.remove(employee);
    }
    ............
    ............
}
```

Is my design compliant with composite design pattern?

Comment: I would move both methods into a manager specific interface which then can extend `Employee`. It makes no sense to me that a "normal" employee can "add" or "remove" other employees.

Comment: Thanks Tom!! I found this code from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the methods of an interface will be applicable to (and have non-empty implementations in) all implementing classes. In your case, since a `Developer` cannot actually have subordinates, I would *strongly* recommend against this. With the current design, consumers of the interface cannot rely on the fact that `Employee`s they send to `add()` will actually be retained anywhere.

As for the Composite design pattern: an interface that is implemented by several classes should only contain the operations that are meaningful to perform on *all* of the classes. There may exist situations in which it is a good idea to do otherwise, but you should carefully consider the consequences of the "not always meaningful" methods potentially being called. In particular, you should document it, and consider throwing an exception instead of doing nothing.

A related operation you *could* safely add to the interface is `public List<Employee> getSubordinates()`. Although a `Developer` doesn't have subordinates, it is still possible for it to react meaningfully to this operation: simply return an empty list.

Comment: So, in composite design pattern we don't insert add and remove methods in parent?

Comment: The interface should have whichever operations are meaningful in _all_ of its implementors. In your case, add/remove isn't always meaningful. In other situations, they might be.

Comment: Thanks Aasmund!! Can you give me some example?

Comment: If the meaning of `add()` is to add a _coworker_ rather than a _subordinate_, it will be meaningful for all kinds of `Employee`s to have that method, since everyone can have coworkers. As a matter of fact, I would have included the relationship type as a part of the method name (`addSubordinate()` or `addCoworker()`), since it's not obvious what it means to just "add" one employee to another.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't.
Check the UML diagram of the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).
You need to have `add` and `remove` methods just for `Manager`
otherwise your design will not match **[Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)**

I would push down `Employee`'s methods :

```
   public void add(Employee employee);
   public void remove(Employee employee);
```

In another interface :

```
public interface SuperiorEmployee extends Employee {

       public void add(Employee employee);
       public void remove(Employee employee);
}

Manager implements SuperiorEmployee {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void add(Employee employee) {
       employees.add(employee);
    }    

    @Override
    public void remove(Employee employee) {
      employees.remove(employee);
    }
    ............
    ............
}
```